# How to monitor postgresql database table for any changes via c#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I have a windows service running which reads configurations from a table from PostgreSQL. These settings are read only once at the time of service startup and for any change in them, the service needs to be restarted. I am looking for a mechanism in C# to monitor any changes on database. So that I would then fetch back the settings on database change.

One approach I was looking for, is to write/modify a text file from PostgreSQL trigger and then use FileWatcher to update the settings. But no success there either.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-notify.html

Comment: for .net check this: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual#working-with-notifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I created a perpetual listening connection with command `listen <channel_name>` by referring [npgsql documentation](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual#working-with-notifications)

Then I wrote a trigger that would fire command

`PERFORM pg_notify('<channel_name>', format('Changed: %s ', NEW.column_name));`

So any change on the particular database's table was captured by the trigger, which in turn sent the notification to the channel and the c# code listened and processed it